# Emit custom validation CSS in asp.net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm attempting to integrate our MVC 5 application with a theme from **{wrap}bootstrap**. It provides its own validation classes (they are different from the out-of-the-box bootstrap validation classes).

Is there a clean way to hook into MVC's validation to emit these CSS classes instead of the default **-validation-error** CSS classes?

Need to end up with this in the event of an error (this would be the emitted html):

```
<input class="invalid" .../>
```

Comment: @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Property, new { @class ="MyCustomCssClass"})

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't dynamically add the CSS class when there's a validation error to let's say, the input element.

Comment: I know. Thus I commented and didn't answer. Afaik, you can't override them dynamically. There is no setting or property you could change. At least when I last checked the mvc sources, there were simply public static readonly string fields with hard coded values.

Comment: Thanks anyway. This could be an issue with the JS files included with the theme. From the digging around, it looks like it should respond when the data attributes are added, but it's not entirely doing what it should.

Comment: Are you just looking to hook to the actual form controls (ie `input`, `select`, `textarea`, etc)? Also AFAIK, mvc doesn't add classes to these controls upon validation.